# Spring Boot Webservice SOAP Error: Content-Encoding must be set to gzip

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, content-type

I am using Spring Boot to call a SOAP webservice and I am sending a file in the envelope. I am using JAXB for XML-creation. When i send the request to the server, it is returning an error, of which i think it is not coming from the endpoint:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-05 09:57:47 | ERROR | main | work.boot.SpringApplication:858   | Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at de.varengold.cdl.mvp.MvpApplication.main(MvpApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Error: HTTP data must be compressed; **Content-Encoding must be set to gzip**

How to set the content encoding to gzip?

This is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication

@Slf4j

public class MvpApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

SpringApplication.run(MvpApplication.class, args);

}

 @Bean
CommandLineRunner lookup(SOAPConnector soapConnector , Config config) {
return args -> {
  SubmitDATTRA request = new SubmitDATTRA();
  FileDataSource ds = new FileDataSource(config.getReportFilePath() );
  request.setDatei(new DataHandler(ds));
  SubmitDATTRAResponse response =(SubmitDATTRAResponse) soapConnector.callWebService(Config.TEST_URL, request);


    };
  }
}
```

The content type is (sysout): application/octet-stream. The file is a gzip file. I think i am close to the solution, but i dont know how to tell spring that it should use content-Encoding=gzip

Here is the SOAPConnector

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;

public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
   public Object callWebService(String url, Object request){
   return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);
   }

}
```

My Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Getter
public class Config {

  public static final String PROD_URL = "https://portal.mvp.bafin.de:444/services/ws/a26mifir";
  public static final String TEST_URL = "https://portal.mvp.bafin.de:444/services/ws/t_a26mifir";

  @Value("${report.file.path}")
  private String reportFilePath;

  @Bean
  public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("de.acme.ws");
    return marshaller;
  }

  @Bean
  public SOAPConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
    client.setDefaultUri(TEST_URL);
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
  }
}
```

I was reading and inspired by this article: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-soap-client-webservicetemplate/

Comment: Is `SOAPConnector` a custom class? Can I have a look into its source code?

Comment: @Dimitry Bogdanovich: Of course, see my updated question

Comment: I have managed to set the content encoding to gzip using http headers